# How can I create a ISODate() from timestamp in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, datetime

I am trying to create a ISODate() from a timestamp but I was unable.

I mean, imagine you want to get current date less 7 days, then what I would do is something like

```
ISODate(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7).toISOString().substring(0,10)
```

And it is okay, however I am getting 1464-10-23 so...

I am trying to do it without `new Date()`!

It is important to me because, it is the only way I can do the query that I need (I have dd/mm/yyyy string dates on the DB) with an aggregation as a far as I know (I am very beginner on mongo)

Comment: Why do you use strings instead of date objects in your database in the first place?

Comment: May be [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) will help you. See the docs to know how to use it.

Comment: This is what I got in a project in which I am working, I of course know that it is not a good format at all....

Comment: It should be something in pure javascript or native with mongo or similar..But why doesn't my solution work?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution doesn't work because the `ISODate` constructor only takes a string parameter, not a timestamp. However, you can use [`Date`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/) in the shell instead:

```
> new Date((new Date()).getTime() - 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7).toISOString().substring(0,10)
2016-05-24
```

`Date` objects in the shell are wrapped by `ISODate`, so this should still work for whatever you want to do.

```
> new Date((new Date()).getTime() - 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7)
ISODate("2016-05-24T15:31:48.335Z")
```

Comment: I knew how to get it that from the new Date, my point was how to get it working in an aggregation so to far as I know I need to wrap it into a ISODate...I think I have solved it although I am not very happy with my implementation..Thank I appreciate it

Comment: Hmm...I don't understand how the two things are related. As shown in the second example, `Date` and `ISODate` are the same thing in the shell.